# Python dictionary ValueError while importing logging configuration

Tags: python, logging, python-2.7

I've searched through google and found only answers regarding Django and it's urls.
My problem is similar but concerns logging issues and I cannot cope with that.

I used [Advanced Logging Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial) and [Logging Cookbook](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#) as well as [logging.conf description](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#module-logging.config)

and always get the error below after running "python logger.py":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logger.py", line 5, in <module>
    logging.config.dictConfig('logger-dict.conf')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 777, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 380, in __init__
    self.config = ConvertingDict(config)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

**logger.py**

```
import logging
import logging.config

logging.config.dictConfig('logger-dict.conf')

logger = logging.getLogger('basic')

logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warn('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')
```

**logger-dict.conf**

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': True,
'formatters': {
    'simple': {
        'format': '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
        'datefmt': '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %Z',
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'console':{
        'level':'DEBUG',
        'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'simple'
    },
    'file':{
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'formatter': 'simple',
        'mode': 'a',
        'filename': './logs/logconfig.log',
        'maxBytes': '1048576',
        'backupCount': '5',
    },

},
'loggers': {
    'basic': {
        'handlers':['file'],
        'propagate': True,
        'level':'INFO',
    },
}
}
```

I have been trying to solve the issue with the answers regarding Django but no success for now.

**EDIT:**

After a comment below I understood that if to put a dictionary somewhere it is better to put it into *.py file instead of *.conf.

But is there an EASY way (not reading file line by line) to use *.conf file with python dictionary inside?

Comment: you are passing filename in logging.config.dictConfig('logger-dict.conf') instead of dictConfig use fileConfig for example logging.config.fileConfig('logger-dict.conf')

Comment: It would work if the file structure was like [this](http://wklej.org/id/1062444/) not like a dictionary.

Comment: But you gave ma a thought to concern. If I put what I have done from *.conf file to *.py file it should work I think.

I just wonder if it can be done the *.conf way.

Comment: @Archarachne Simply do `import ast; with open('logger-dict.conf') as f: config = ast.literal_eval(f.read())`. Note that is is safer than putting the dictionary into a `.py`, since it avoids arbitrary code execution. Note that the file should contain *only* the dictionary literal, not the `LOGGING = ` part.

Comment: Should *.conf then include only one dictionary?
And if I want another e.g. for keeping some other data I should have another *.conf file, yes?

And thank you, your way works fine.